# Replacing a character at specific location in a file

Tags: text-processing, sed

i have a file as follows and would like to replace the comma in second position with a # :

```
1K,1,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2837726134152E+08,0.6756896377655E+02
1K,2,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2837950666514E+08,0.6757007624345E+02
1K,3,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2837975330813E+08,0.6756827852038E+02
1K,8,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2610685746631E+08,0.1832495587770E+03
1K,9,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2610716318002E+08,0.1836118051089E+03
1K10,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2609596327361E+08,0.1822385749588E+03
1K11,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2610713453046E+08,0.1841214115744E+03
1K12,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2610673990054E+08,0.1846882770826E+03
1K18,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2610076439025E+08,0.1854595804085E+03
```

I tried this but deleting the characters before the comma :

```
sed 's/^\(.\{2\}\),/\#/' input_file
```

Achieved result:

```
#1,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2837726134152E+08,0.6756896377655E+02
#2,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2837950666514E+08,0.6757007624345E+02
#3,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2837975330813E+08,0.6756827852038E+02
#8,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2610685746631E+08,0.1832495587770E+03
#9,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2610716318002E+08,0.1836118051089E+03
1K10,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2609596327361E+08,0.1822385749588E+03
1K11,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2610713453046E+08,0.1841214115744E+03
1K12,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2610673990054E+08,0.1846882770826E+03
1K18,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2610076439025E+08,0.1854595804085E+03
```

Desired result:

```
1K#1,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2837726134152E+08,0.6756896377655E+02
1K#2,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2837950666514E+08,0.6757007624345E+02
1K#3,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2837975330813E+08,0.6756827852038E+02
1K#8,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2610685746631E+08,0.1832495587770E+03
1K#9,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2610716318002E+08,0.1836118051089E+03
1K10,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2609596327361E+08,0.1822385749588E+03
1K11,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2610713453046E+08,0.1841214115744E+03
1K12,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2610673990054E+08,0.1846882770826E+03
1K18,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2610076439025E+08,0.1854595804085E+03
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the comma `,` that needs to be replaced with `#` is in position **3**:

```
sed 's/^\(..\),/\1#/' input_file
```

- `^` - start of the string anchor
- `(..)` - the 1st captured group containing the 1st 2 chars
- `\1` - reference to the 1st captured group

---

The output:

```
1K#1,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2837726134152E+08,0.6756896377655E+02
1K#2,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2837950666514E+08,0.6757007624345E+02
1K#3,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2837975330813E+08,0.6756827852038E+02
1K#8,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2610685746631E+08,0.1832495587770E+03
1K#9,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2610716318002E+08,0.1836118051089E+03
1K10,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2609596327361E+08,0.1822385749588E+03
1K11,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2610713453046E+08,0.1841214115744E+03
1K12,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2610673990054E+08,0.1846882770826E+03
1K18,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2610076439025E+08,0.1854595804085E+03
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/^\(..\),\([0-9]\)/\1#\2/' input_file
```

Looks like you are not familiar with regexp. This question is as easy as a should-not-be-asked question.

Answer (score 0):

```
use below command to get the desired result

input file u.txt

1K,1,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2837726134152E+08,0.6756896377655E+02
1K,2,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2837950666514E+08,0.6757007624345E+02
1K,3,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2837975330813E+08,0.6756827852038E+02
1K,8,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2610685746631E+08,0.1832495587770E+03
1K,9,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2610716318002E+08,0.1836118051089E+03
1K10,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2609596327361E+08,0.1822385749588E+03
1K11,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2610713453046E+08,0.1841214115744E+03
1K12,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2610673990054E+08,0.1846882770826E+03
1K18,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2610076439025E+08,0.1854595804085E+03


command: sed "s/,/#/1" u.txt

sed "s/,/#/1" u.txt 
1K#1,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2837726134152E+08,0.6756896377655E+02
1K#2,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2837950666514E+08,0.6757007624345E+02
1K#3,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2837975330813E+08,0.6756827852038E+02
1K#8,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2610685746631E+08,0.1832495587770E+03
1K#9,,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2610716318002E+08,0.1836118051089E+03
1K10#,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2609596327361E+08,0.1822385749588E+03
1K11#,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2610713453046E+08,0.1841214115744E+03
1K12#,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2610673990054E+08,0.1846882770826E+03
1K18#,,,,,,,,,,0.10000000E+00,0.2610076439025E+08,0.1854595804085E+03
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can make a pattern in which every "K," appearance must be "K#", you can make the following `sed` substitution:

```
sed 's/K,/K#/g' input_file
```

Comment: Acutally, for this specific case, I think your answer is simple enough, and better than others, including mine.